# displaying a map in the background with matplotlib animation

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to show a map in the background when a vehicle is moving.  I am using matplotlib animate function.  The movement looks fine.  But I tried the following while loading the map.  The map is not loading.  Only a black patch is visible.  I tried to specify the zorder as well.  but nothing works.

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, len(x11),interval=150,
                          blit=True, init_func=init, repeat=False)

img = cbook.get_sample_data('..\\maps.png')
image = plt.imread(img)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read background image with `scipy.misc import imread` and use `plt.imshow` to render in the background of your animation.

Below example generates a circle (we'll assume its your car), puts "usa_map.jpg" in the background and then moves circle over map.

Bonus, you can save the animation using encoders such as `ffmpeg` as a movie in `mp4` format using `anim.save('the_movie.mp4', writer = 'ffmpeg', fps=30)`

**Source Code**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from scipy.misc import imread


img = imread("usa_map.jpg")

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_dpi(100)
fig.set_size_inches(7, 6.5)

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 20), ylim=(0, 20))
patch = plt.Circle((5, -5), 0.75, fc='y')


def init():
    patch.center = (20, 20)
    ax.add_patch(patch)
    return patch,

def animate(i):
    x = 10 + 3 * np.sin(np.radians(i))
    y = 10 + 3 * np.cos(np.radians(i))
    patch.center = (x, y)
    return patch,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 
                               init_func=init, 
                               frames=360, 
                               interval=20,
                               blit=True)

plt.imshow(img,zorder=0,  extent=[0.1, 20.0, 0.1, 20.0])
anim.save('the_movie.mp4', writer = 'ffmpeg', fps=30)
plt.show()
```

Above code will generate animaton with a circle moving around USA map. It will also be saved as 'the_movie.mp4' , which I cant upload here.

**Result Image**
[image]